# Communication between two docker images

Tags: docker, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I have a docker image for spark named `spark-docker` and the cassandra official docker image `cassandra`. I want to run a spark-submit job from `spark-docker`which will write data in cassandra.

The `Dockerfile` for `spark-docker` is as follows:

```
FROM bde2020/spark-python-template:2.4.0-hadoop2.7

MAINTAINER Rafiul

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pyspark cassandra-driver
```

I am using the following command to do that.

```
docker run -ti --network=dockers_default spark-dcoker:latest /spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra  --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.4.0-s_2.11 /app/data_extractor.py -f /app/dataset.tar
```

This will extract data from `dataset.tar` and will save the data in cassandra.

But I am getting the following error

```
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

In my python code I have done this:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster


class CassandraSchemaGenerator:
    def __init__(self, keyspace):
        self.keyspace = keyspace
        self.cluster = Cluster()
        self.cluster_conn = self.cluster.connect()
```

How can I get the IP address and port number on which cassandra is running and put it in my python code so that it can connect to cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use `127.0.0.1` to connect from one container to another unless you are not using `network=host`.

So, you do one of the following:

Switch to `network=host` mode when starting containers (this mode requires no port exposion)

Or (better) join both containers in your network and use container names as host names to connect between them:

```
docker network create foo
docker run --network=foo -d  --name=cassy cassandra
docker run --network=foo -ti --name=spark spark-docker:latest ...
```

Note `name` argument - this allows containers have human readable names.
Now from `spark` you can connect to cassandra using host name `cassy` instead of ip

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the second part, the docker command should be something like that:

`docker run -ti --network=host spark-dcoker:latest /spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassy  --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.4.0-s_2.11 /app/data_extractor.py -f /app/dataset.tar`

Is it so? 

In this case, do I need to specify the port as well in my python code?

Comment: Yes, the command line is longer, I reduced it for readability. I cant help you on whether you need to specify ports because I dont know cassandra nor spark. But I think they are both configured to use default ports and in this case it will work by default

Comment: Tried both separately, same problem with host and port. :(